# How to use a regex in MongoDB to search for a word at the end of a string?

Tags: regex, database, string, mongodb, sqlite

```
mysteryRestaurant = []
for rest in restaurants.find({"name": {"$regex" : "/Palace$/"}}):
    mysteryRestaurant.append(rest)
result = pd.DataFrame(mysteryRestaurant)
result
```

My code is above, I'm trying to find all the names of restaurants that have the word "Palace" at the end of its name. That's what I ran above, and I am getting nothing in return. I'm getting no errors or anything else like that. I'm just getting a blank run. Not sure what that means. What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: See the docs about using the [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html). Why are you using the `/`s? Are they necessary?

Comment: @prasad_ oh wait you're right, I removed them and it worked. thanks!